# How to get all data attribute values inside every tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tab and inside each tab, there are some divs with "data" attributes. I need all data attributes for each tab separately.

```js
$('#myTab a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});

$(function() {
  $('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
})

$('.save').on('click', function() {
  var dataNid = [];

  $('.tab-pane').each(function(index, value) {

    $(this).find('div').each(function(i, item) {
      dataNid.push($(this).data('id'));
    })
    console.log('Tab Pane' + index + ' TAB ID: ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' DATA-NID: ' + dataNid);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
      <div data-id="1">1</div>
      <div data-id="2">2</div>
      <div data-id="3">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
      <div data-id="1">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
      <div data-id="3">3</div>
      <div data-id="1">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
```

Currently I am getting like this:
Tab Pane0 TAB ID: home DATA-NID: 1,2,3
Tab Pane1 TAB ID: profile DATA-NID: 1,2,3,1
Tab Pane2 TAB ID: messages DATA-NID: 1,2,3,1,3,1

But I want like this:
Tab Pane0 TAB ID: home DATA-NID: 1,2,3
Tab Pane1 TAB ID: profile DATA-NID: 1
Tab Pane2 TAB ID: messages DATA-NID: 3,1

Can anyone please help me to figure out this?

Thanks,

Comment: `var dataNid = [];` is the same array for all three pane... So the result is quite normal. What's preventing you to fix it?

Comment: @Bryce77 @sjahan basically answered your question: the `dataNid = []` is an array that's being declared at the beginning, and thus not cleared

Comment: Yes, thats correct. I am lost there. How to create separate arrays for each tab.

Comment: To clarify the above comments: just move `var dataNid = [];` inside the `$('.tab-pane').each(` loop.  Javascript is a bit funny about where variables are *declared*, but it is *initialised* with `=[]` which should be inside the loop.

Comment: Haha I though he wanted only the "ids" of the selected tab so I was asnwering that he just had to replace `$('.tab-pane').each(` by `$('.tab-pane.active').each(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the snippet is running and you took some time to provide it, here is the solution.

Just move the array `dataNid` so that you use a new one for each pane.

```js
$('#myTab a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});

$(function() {
  $('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
})

$('.save').on('click', function() {


  $('.tab-pane').each(function(index, value) {

    var dataNid = [];

    $(this).find('div').each(function(i, item) {
      dataNid.push($(this).data('id'));
    })
    console.log('Tab Pane' + index + ' TAB ID: ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' DATA-NID: ' + dataNid);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
      <div data-id="1">1</div>
      <div data-id="2">2</div>
      <div data-id="3">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
      <div data-id="1">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
      <div data-id="3">3</div>
      <div data-id="1">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your `var dataNid = []` being initialised BEFORE your function call.

Thus, since you do not reinitialize your array on each function call, you just keep adding to this same `dataNid`

```
$('.save').on('click', function(){
    //var dataNid = []; //remove this

    $('.tab-pane').each(function (index, value) {
            var dataNid = []; //move it HERE!
            $(this).find('div').each(function(i, item){
                dataNid.push($(this).data('id'));
            })
            console.log('Tab Pane' + index + ' TAB ID: ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' DATA-NID: ' + dataNid); 
        });
});
```

Comment: Yes, same like @sjahan. Thanks!